# How to cast a let variable in swift

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have created let variable with identifier varA, Then assigned a integer value to the same.

```
import cocoa
var varA = 42
```

After these line i would like to have this varA to be **store an float value**.

> Just like in python i have used this feature

Im getting
`error: cannot assign to 'let' value 'varA'`

How can i do this?
Im using swift 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After these line i would like to have this varA to be store an float value.

Nope, you can't do that in Swift.

Swift is statically typed. You can never change a variable's type after the declaration. You can only create another variable to store the value. In your case, there are a few other solutions available as well.

Solution 1

Since `Float` can store integers as well, declare `varA` to be of type `Float` in the first place:

```
var varA: Float = 42
varA = 0.5
```

Solution 2

Create another variable:

```
var varA = 42
var anotherVar: Float = varA
```

Solution 3

Use `Any`. This makes the variable able to store anything (This is highly *not* recommended)

```
var varA: Any = 42
varA = 0.5
```

Comment: Great.. Why this 3rd option is not recomanded in swift.  How much  memory they could have alloted in that case?

Comment: @Saranjith If you use the third option, you need to keep casting from `Any` to whatever type you want. This makes the code look ugly.